# BorderLayout and JScrollPane problems

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, border-layout

I have a `JFrame` with three areas:

- A scrollpane with a list of objects
- A panel with labels and textfields
- A scrollpane with a panel potentially having multiple labels

When you click the item on the list, the textfields on the panel are filled and the labels on the second scroll are created. I have two problems with my code:

1. For some reason the scrollpane at the botom of the screen does not fill the whole borderlayout's south area, only half of it.
2. the scrollpane does not show anything when the item on the list is selected.

Here I tried to make an example:

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JPanel geral = new JPanel();
    JPanel lista = new JPanel();
    JPanel dados = new JPanel();
    JPanel paneHist = new JPanel();
    JPanel historico = new JPanel();
    GridLayout gridLay = new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 10);
    geral.setLayout(gridLay);
    dados.setLayout(gridLay);
    historico.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    lista.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    paneHist.setLayout(gridLay);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(geral);
    geral.add(lista, BorderLayout.WEST);
    geral.add(dados, BorderLayout.EAST);
    geral.add(historico, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listModel.addElement("just testing");

    final JList list = new JList(listModel);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setVisible(true);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 500));

    lista.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
    dados.add(new JLabel("test:"));
    dados.add(jtf);

    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
            jtf.setText("clicked");
            paneHist.add(new JLabel("texttexttext"));
            paneHist.add(new JLabel("texttexttext"));
        }}
    );
    JScrollPane scrollHist = new JScrollPane(paneHist);
    scrollHist.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
    historico.add(new JLabel("Historico:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    historico.add(scrollHist, BorderLayout.EAST);
    //list.setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());

    this.validate();
    this.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell what you are doing from the posted code.

Some general comments:

1. Don't use setPreferredSize(). Let each component determined its preferred size. In the case of a JList you can use the `setVisibleRowCount(...)` method so the JList can calculate a reasonable size.
2. In your ListSelectionListener, when you add/remove components from a visible GUI you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the panel.

Comment: I am trying to make components appear in the scrollpane (scrollHist) at the bottom of the UI whenever you select an item in the scrollpane (scroll) at the side of the UI. What exactly are you not understanding? maybe I can try to explain better.

Comment: `What exactly are you not understanding?`  The complicated layout of your components. I don't know the context of how the code is used. I don't know what "this" refers to. Is it a frame or another panel? If it is a frame, then it appears like you are removing all the components from the frame and then adding all new components. The general rule is don't do this. Instead add the components at design time. Then when the event is generated you just add data to the components so you don't have to worry about rebuilding the entire GU. Post a proper `SSCCE` if you need more help.

Comment: "this" refers to the frame, yes. Sorry about the SSCCE, I should have said that the method posted is called by a Menu Item in a JMenuBar. The rest of the code is just the main calling the frame constructor with initComponents() and a bunch of auto-generated stuff from the IDE, so I'm not really sure what else I should include/remove from the post.
About adding components at design time, do you have a quick reference to help me grasp what you mean? I am failing to see how I could navigate through diferent screens in the same frame without rebuilding the UI on the fly.

Comment: Start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). The example there swaps panels when you select an item from a combo box. In your case you would swap panels when you click on a menu item.

Comment: Alright, I will try to rewrite the program the way you suggested and then I will come back to say how it went. Do you think it will fix the scrollpane/borderlayout problem or is there any other more direct ideia that I could try first?